# Web Standard for minimum size of touch icons

Tags: touch-screen

Regarding menu icons on mobile devices, are there any official web accessibility standards for the minimum size/area of touch?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11259/so-how-big-is-the-mouse-pointer/11426

Comment: @DominikOslizlo isn't that question related to mouse pointer?

Comment: @DaveHaigh, you are correct, I misread the question - sorry for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft put together some UI guidelines for designing their Windows 8 store apps. These could apply to any touch based UI.

Take a look at the section **Touch, Commanding, and Controls** beginning on page **65**

**Windows 8 User Experience Guidelines:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465424.aspx

**Direct download:** http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=258743

In particular relating to minimum sizes for touch see page **74-75**

> People often blame themselves for having "fat fingers." But even baby
> fingers are wider than most touch targets. The image on the left shows
> that the width of the average adult finger is about 11 millimeters
> (mm) wide, while a baby's is 8 mm, and some basketball players have
> fingers wider than 19 mm!

[image]
.

> **7x7 mm**: Recommended minimum size **7x7 mm** is a good minimum size if
> touching the wrong target can be corrected in one or two gestures or
> within five seconds. Padding between targets is just as important as
> target size.
>
> **When accuracy matters** Close, delete, and other actions
> with severe consequences can’t afford accidental taps. Use **9x9 mm**
> targets if touching the wrong target requires more than two gestures,
> five seconds, or a major context change to correct.
>
> **When it just
> doesn’t fit** If you find yourself cramming things to fit, it’s okay to
> use **5x5 mm** targets as long as touching the wrong target can be
> corrected with one gesture. Using 2 mm of padding between targets is
> extremely important in this case.

[image]

Comment: Plus a nice article (a bit old, but still quite valid): http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2012/02/21/finger-friendly-design-ideal-mobile-touchscreen-target-sizes/

Comment: great article here called: Common Misconceptions About Touch http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2013/03/common-misconceptions-about-touch.php